# How to make GitHub re-run a step that is a dependency of a step that is being retried?

Tags: github-actions

I have a `test` workflow that depends on `scale_up` to complete:

```yaml
scale_up:
    # I was expecting this to do the job, but the workflow does not run when
    # doing on 
    if: always()
    name: scale up
    needs:
      - deploy
    runs-on:
      - self-hosted
      - contra-general-purpose
    steps:
      - name: checkout repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: scale up contra-api
        run: kubectl scale deployment/gaia-review-contra-api --replicas 5
test_playwright:
    name: 'test (playwright)'
    needs:
      - scale_up
    runs-on:
      - self-hosted
      - contra-general-purpose
    steps:
      - name: checkout repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
    ...
```

The idea is that we scale up the infrastructure that supports the tests before running tests and scale down after.

The problem happens if `test (playwright)` step fails and we choose [github](/questions/tagged/github) option to retry only the failing step:

[image]

What I expect to happen, is that GitHub identifies the `if: always()` dependency and re-runs it.

What actually happens is that [github](/questions/tagged/github) re-runs literally only the identified job.

How do I made it so that GitHub re-runs steps that a step being retried depends on?

Comment: As you are choosing the "re-run failed jobs", GitHub ignores the jobs which are succeed and only select the failed job and the jobs dependent on it. This is the expected behavior.  You can choose the option to run all jobs.

Comment: Then how is one supposed to implement a step that is run once before all the shards executed?

Comment: Seems like a rudimentary requirement of a CI/CD to be able to setup the test environment before running the tests.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue. As a workaround, I decided to use GitHub webhooks, specifically the [workflow_Job](https://docs.github.com/en/webhooks/webhook-events-and-payloads#workflow_job) event.

I have an API endpoint that is called when the `workflow_Job` webhook is triggered. The endpoint checks for a few conditions like action type, workflow name and job name and in my case, spins up an EC2 instance for the job to run on.

The webhook is also triggered when you re-run failed jobs, so it will always spin up an EC2 instance.

I know it's a bit of a boilerplate, but it's the best solution I could find with re-running failed jobs.

Comment: That's fine as a comment, but it doesn't answer the question.